# Variable that can store several data types

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, polymorphism, generic-programming

I need to create a class that can store in a variable a value of type either `Person`, `Dog` or `Cat`.

I'd like to declare one variable because only one object of an specific type will be used to initialize the instance of the class. Declaring a variable for each type would be a waste of resources as only one would be used.

Consider this:

```
Class Container {
    private Object object;
    ...
    Container(Person a){
        object = a;
    }
    Container(Dog a){
        object = a;
    }
    Container(Cat a){
        object = a;
    }
    ...
}
```

And then do:

```
Container contA = new Container(A);
Container contB = new Container(B);

System.out.println(contA.getObject().toString());
System.out.println(contA.getObject().toString());
```

And ideally get the correct output in console.

I looked into generics and other stuff but was unable to find anything like what I needed. Could you point me to what I'm looking for?

The `getObject()` in `Container` could handle the type with an `instanceof` but the return type of `getObject()` would have to be `Object` and that won't work.

I'm learning Java and this is really bugging me.

Should I instead use inheritance and create a subclass to handle each type?

Comment: *Declaring a variable for each type would be a waste of resources as only one would be used.* - why do you think this?

Comment: *Should I instead use inheritance and create a subclass to handle each type?* sounds like a better idea

Comment: I'm assuming that if I declare three variables, the system will reserve the space for three variables. Is inheritance the way to go then? Thanks @ScaryWombat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use generics (how you already guessed):

```
public class Container<T> {
    T object;
    Container(T a) {
        object = a;
    }

    T getObject() {
        return object;
    }
}
```

or an (marker) interface (a generalization).
In your following code you can go on working with Mammal instead of distinguishing between Cats and Dogs:

```
public interface Mammal {
}

public class Container {
    Mammal object;
    Container(Mammal a) {
        object = a;
    }

    Mammal getObject() {
        return object;
    }
}

public class Cat implements Mammal {...
public class Dog implements Mammal {...
public class Person implements Mammal {...
```

> Interfaces relate the classes together giving them a meaning while generics do not. (Muhammad Ali)

Comment: Is generics the same as Templates in C++? This really sounds like the way to go. Actually, generics popped up in the searches before posting the question but wanted something like a template / generic for only the variable.

Comment: what do you mean by _really belong together_? Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: @DanielSegura yes its the same concept as C++ templates. To use generics for class variables you need to use a generic class.

And: see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html for interfaces. You can use them either as public interfaces to form contracts etc or as marker interface to mark special classes.

Answer (score 2):

Add an interface say `MeatBall`. Derive all of your three classes from `MeatBall`. Now make a constructor that takes meatball as input. Store it in a similar fashion.

Comment: Why was this voted down? Isn't this how we handle persons, dogs and cats in Java?

Comment: Sounds good. I'll learn a bit about interfaces and see if works for me. What's your opinion on using _generics_?

Comment: Interfaces relate the classes together giving them a meaning while generics do not.

Comment: @MuhammadAli well said! I allowed to add your statement in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Two Possibilities are.

1. Super Class.

   - Take a super class That has some common behaviour and extend all your
     classes.
   - Now declare the super class reference to store it sub class.
   - Here you can use generics bounds.
   - Take a look at here [Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html)
2. Use Interface.

   - Declare interface and implement all of your classes.
   - Now declare that reference in your class to hold your objects.
   - Take a look at here [interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/usinginterface.html).

You can use instanceof operator and type casting to deal with sub class specific features.

Comment: I'll look for a Generics vs Interfaces comparison and see what works best for me, but really guess that the answers is either. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel why don't you have multiple if blocks checking respective type and do the conditional operation?

Like:

```
class Container {
    private Object object;

    Container() {

    }

    Container(Object a) {
        object = a;
    }

    public Object getInstance(){
        return object;
    }
}

class Dog extends Container {

    Dog() {

    }

    Dog(Object a) {
        super(a);
    }
}

class Cat extends Container {

    Cat() {

    }

    Cat(Object a) {
        super(a);
    }
}

public class ExampleCode {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog dogRef = new Dog();
        Cat catRef = new Cat();

        Container contReference1 = new Container(dogRef); 

        if(contReference1.getInstance() instanceof Dog)
        {
            System.out.println("Its a Dog");
        }else if(contReference1.getInstance() instanceof Cat)
        {
            System.out.println("Its a Cat");
        }else
        {
            System.out.println("Error: Unknown Object");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But where would the hypothetical A, B, C be stored? Is this supposed to be used in conjunction with inheritance or a generic? Thanks!

Comment: Daniel, Updated my answer. Let me know if it serve the purpose now.